# ERROR Error: ng-charts configuration error, data or datasets field are required to render chart line

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using **ng-charts 2.4.0** and **chart.js 2.9.3** for loading charts in **Angular 10.0.14** version.

Charts are loading but an error coming up in console as,

```
ERROR Error: ng-charts configuration error, data or datasets field are required to render chart line
```

Why I'm getting this error? Any suggestions to fix this?

this is my HTML code

```
<div style="display: block;" *ngIf="chartDataReady">
  <canvas baseChart 
    [datasets]="barChartData"
    [labels]="barChartLabels"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [colors]="chartColor"
    [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
    [legend]="barChartLegend"
    [chartType]="barChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

My type Script code

```
 public barChartOptions: object;
 public barChartLabels: Label[];
 public barChartType: ChartType = 'line';
 public barChartLegend = true;
 public barChartPlugins = [];
 public chartColor = [];
 public barChartData: any[];

  this.barChartData = [
      {
        data: [
          '427.107858491441',
          '583.107858491441',
          '693.848606343664',
          '843.107858491441',
          '953.848606343664'
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 165, 165, 1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 165, 165, 1)',
        fill: false,
        label: 'High 95'
      },
      {
        data: [
          '234.085360485402',
          '390.085360485402',
          '420.873571820389',
          '650.085360485402'
        ],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(187, 41, 25,1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(187, 41, 25,1)",
        fill: false,
        label: "Low 80"
      }
    ];
    this.barChartLabels = ["Jun 1, 2017", "Jul 1, 2017", "Aug 1, 2017", "Sep 1, 2017", "Oct 1, 2017", "Nov 1, 2017", "Dec 1, 2017", "Jan 1, 2018", "Feb 1, 2018", "Mar 1, 2018", "Apr 1, 2018", "May 1, 2018", "Jun 1, 2018", "Jul 1, 2018", "Aug 1, 2018", "Sep 1, 2018", "Oct 1, 2018", "Nov 1, 2018", "Dec 1, 2018"]
    this.barChartOptions = {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
        labels: {
          fontColor: '#000080'
        }
      },
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: 'Extreme Intervals'
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'X-axis Low',
              fontColor: '#000080'
            }
          }
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Y-axis High',
              fontColor: '#000080'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
    this.chartColor = [
        {
          borderColor: 'rgba(0, 165, 165, 1)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 165, 165, 1)'
        },
        {
          borderColor: 'rgba(187, 41, 25,1)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(187, 41, 25,1)'
        }
      ]
```

This is my type and HTML code loading this data on ngOnInit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the chart after you have received your data.

When you've built your chart, assign a variable like this.

`chartDataReady = true;`

In your HTML, you can wrap the chart with a `*ngIf` like this.

`*ngIf="chartDataReady"`

Comment: yes. i tried with this approach also but still error is been populating in the console

Comment: Can you add the typescript code and the HTML to your question?

Comment: "ngIf="chartDataReady" is set to false, chart is hidden but still error populating in the console as   ERROR Error: ng-charts configuration error, data or datasets field are required to render chart line
    at BaseChartDirective.getDatasets (ng2-charts.js:864)
    at BaseChartDirective.getChartConfiguration (ng2-charts.js:667)